# Boot time discrepancy using systemd on Debian 7.4

Tags: debian, systemd, fsck

I recently installed `systemd` on my Debian 7.4 system. The time from pressing the power button to usable desktop is around 42-44 seconds. The BIOS takes 6-7 seconds to load and transfer control to GRUB. GRUB has a timeout of 0, in `/etc/default/grub`. After that the system takes almost 35 seconds more. However, `systemd` reports taking just 19 seconds.

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4353ms (kernel) + 14291ms (userspace) = 18644ms
```

That means, that there is a 16 second delay somewhere. This delay appears to  occur just after GRUB finishes and transfers control to the OS. The boot process gets stuck on a screen that says "Loading, please wait" for this time. After the 16 seconds pass, I get a feedback stating these two things:

```
systemd-fsck [..] : /dev/sda1 .... clean
... bad mmio address ...
```

Firstly, what is taking these extra 16 seconds? Is it `fsck` or the `mmio` address error?

I feel that it is `systemd-fsck`, and I have tried to solve the problem. I have edited `/etc/fstab` and changed the `pass` parameter to 0 for all volumes. However, this still continues to occur. So, how do I disable `fsck` on boot for the root (/dev/sda1) partition, or otherwise reduce the time during boot? [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1157702) suggests a solution for non-root drives, which I haven't attempted on `/`.

Comment: Look at the rest of the [systemd-analyze tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_boot_performance)...

Comment: Then you could try the kernel parameters `systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=kmsg log_buf_len=1M` for more verbose detail.

Comment: @jasonwryan `systemd` doesn't even seem to know about the extra 16 seconds. Will the debug mode be useful? At best, I think it will get me more detail about the 19 seconds that it records, not the rest.

Comment: I don't know, I've never had to use it. You will get a lot more logging detail, which may help pinpoint the issue.